# Please help me identify this LED from a Nuevo (HGH0242) / Horizon Lighting 5-pendant light fixture

Tags: led, identification, lighting

[image: Mystery LED]

This is an apparently failed LED from a 5-year-old Nuevo (HGH0242) / Horizon Lighting 5-pendant light fixture in my house.  Only this one has failed - all others still work.  It measures about 11.7 mm wide, 14.5 mm long.  The aluminum (?) coupon it is mounted on is about 1mm thick and the LED protrudes about 0.7mm above that.  Note that it is essentially a lens-less flat disc, not a hemi-sphere.  My guess is that color is about 3000-3500K.  The power supply, which still works (verified by powering other identical pendants), is rated for 350 mA (constant current), 12 W, 21-36Vdc.  This power supply powers two of these pendants in series.  The other (different) power supply powers the other three.  It appears that the number "3713" and "+" and "-" marks are shown in the solder mask.  An ohm meter shows an open circuit across the part.  The series string of two pendants fails when this one was in it and lights when I substitute another identical pendant for this one. I've tried the big-3 suppliers without success and my Google-Fu has failed me.  I'm trying to replace just this one instead of having to perform surgery on all 5 of the pendants in the (expensive) fixture so they all match in color and brightness. TIA for any help.

Comment: Could the number be 13713? The distance between the apparent '-' terminal label and the first '3' looks about equal to the distance between the '7' and '1' in '3713.

Comment: this may help ... search `cob led` ... (chip on board) ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cob+led&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Need some measurments on that LED from calipers

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the first vertical bar is not a '1' but is a (redundant) marking to indicate the negative terminal on the module.

Comment: Regarding the measurements:  I used a machinist's rule, not calipers.  I expect that I got within about +-1/8mm.  I expect the process to shear these from the master sheet is not even that accurate.  Will it be helpful if I give more accurate measurements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find a COB LED (Chip on board Led), 350 mA, with a voltage range of 10-18 Vdc, more or less 5W. More or less 600 lm.
The number of lumens can be very different, it's just an estimate for 120lm/W. It can be as low as 300lm. But it helps narrow the search.

The voltage of the LED is equal to the voltage of the power supply divided by the number of LEDs in series. (Check if there are really in series). It's important that it matches the voltage range. The voltage range can be more or less 2V for the lower and the upper limit and can be narrower than what I wrote.

For example I found [this one](https://gekpower.com/products/constant-current-cob-led-350ma-5w-14-16v) and [this one](http://lightsandparts.com/product/constant-current-cob-led-350ma-5w-15-17v-3000k/).
You can go to other vendors as long as the parameters are respected.

Comment: I may have to go the route of replacing all of the LED assemblies, but my first choice would be to find a drop-in replacement so I can replace only 1 instead of 5.  The pendant lights are close enough together that it is not likely that a different LED would have close enough color and intensity to be a good enough match for the others. Thanks though, I appreciate the information.

Comment: @OCPatch Even if you could find the specific model there would probably be some color difference between one that was made and operated for 5 years and one made this year.  If color matching matters, replace them all.

Comment: @OCPatch If you replace them all, I advise you to replace the power supplies too and even the series configuration if you can (but be careful)  in order to have a wider choice of LEDs. It may be even cheaper since original equivalent cost $11 each.

Comment: @Fredled  You make a really good point.  I was too focused on keeping the job small and replacing only the one LED.  Now I have pretty much bitten the bullet on the idea of replacing them all but am stuck with really poor selection for replacements because I'm almost artificially constraining myself to using the existing power supplies.  The power supplies are relatively cheap and an order of magnitude easier to replace compared to the LED's.  Ironically, before I got the fixture apart, I was sure that it was going to be a defective power supply, not an LED.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  In all of my searching, I found exactly *one* COB LED that met all of my criteria for current, voltage, and size.  It is the one suggested by Fredled and the GEKpower people have bent over backward to accommodate me when the original order confirmation did not seem correct.  I have decided to keep the existing power supplies and try these LED's.  Thanks everyone.